# How to undeclare an already declared class?

Tags: php, object

Suppose a PHP script uses methods of **class A** and then **regenerates new source code** of class A.

If class A is already declared, does PHP provide a method to **undeclare class A** so that I may **re-require the newly created source** of class A?

By 'already declared' I mean, that the source of a class has been parsed, thus the class name is defined and bound to the class definition.

**Update 2014-02-22**

[RunKit](http://docs.php.net/runkit) does provide the [runkit_constant_remove](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-remove.php). Without using RunKit, there **doesn't seem to be a method to undeclared / undefine a class**.

Comment: 1) Generates through Reflection API? 2) What do you mean already defined? Included? 3) (Proposal) Place new code in different location and require it from there. If using namespace just change it from one that uses original class A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible in PHP. There are extensions for defining methods, extending classes at runtime, etc, but none for completely undefining a class so you may redefine it.